# Setear un objeto en setstate react native

Tags: react-native

Estoy intentando setear un objeto dentro de un array en un `setState`, pero lo devuelve vacío:

```
const [generalData, setGeneralData] =  useState<any | null>([]);
  const mapMyAccount = () => {
      
      const accounts = {
        title: 'my account',
        iconName: 'account',
        key: 1,
        items: [
          {
            itemType: 'name',
            currentValue: "n", 
            placeholder: false,
            alert: false,
            editView: 'UserEdit',
            key: 1,
          },
        ],
      }
      
      setGeneralData(accounts);
      // devuelve vacio
      console.log(generalData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los estados no son actualizados automaticamente o en cascada,los estados deben ser escuchados ,debes hacer uso de useEffect para estar monitoreando tu estado,cada que tu estado sea modificado el useEffect si puede obtener el valor actual.

```
const [generalData, setGeneralData] =  useState<any | null>([]);
  const mapMyAccount = () => {
      
      const accounts = {
        title: 'my account',
        iconName: 'account',
        key: 1,
        items: [
          {
            itemType: 'name',
            currentValue: "n", 
            placeholder: false,
            alert: false,
            editView: 'UserEdit',
            key: 1,
          },
        ],
      }
      
      setGeneralData(accounts);
      
    };
 useEffect(() => {
   if(generalData)
    {
      console.log(generalData);
    }
  }, [generalData]);
```